# Encapsulate socket.io inside a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, rollupjs

I'm trying to encapsulate socket.io inside a class, so I can share the same socket in multiple files (using import). This is the common way to use WebSockets if you are using only one file

**Test.js**

```js
let ip = "http://localhost/";
let socket = io(ip);
socket.emit("message", {"content": "hello"});

socket.on("messageResponse", function(content) {
  //Do something here.
});
```

---

What I'm trying to achieve is..

**multiplayer/Socket.js**

```js
class Socket {
    constructor(ip) {
        this.socket = io(ip);
    }

    sendMessage(message, data) {
        this.socket.emit(message, data);
    }
}

export default Socket;
```

**A.js**

```js
import Socket from "./multiplayer/Socket.js";

//listen to certain events here like socket.on("connect")
```

**B.js**

```js
import Socket from "./multiplayer/Socket.js";

//listen to some other events here like socket.on("chatMessage")
```

But I don't know how to encapsule the on event. I'm using rollup to bundle the script inside one single file.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to create a singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to create a singleton

You can do that by exporting a version of your socket object that everything will share:

```
class Socket {
    constructor(ip) {
        this.socket = io(ip);
    }

    sendMessage(message, data) {
        this.socket.emit(message, data);
    }
}

export default new Socket('some_ip');
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
import s from "./multiplayer/Socket.js";

s.socket.on('something', doSomething);
```

and every place you import that socket object it will share all of the same information

Comment: Thanks! Although I modified it a bit, added a new function on the class that returns this.socket and then I've been using like Socket.getSocket().on("message", function);